# System.Xml.XmlException: The element cannot contain white space. Content model is empty

Tags: c#, .net, xml, validation, dtd

I am using Dtd to validate an xml string I receive from users, and I keep getting this exception :

```
System.Xml.XmlException: The element cannot contain white space. 
Content model is empty. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: 
The element cannot contain white space. Content model is empty.
---> System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaException: 
The element cannot contain white space. Content model is empty.
```

How to remove those invalid  white space characters from an XML string ?

I've been struggling with this for the past 3 hours.

Here's the method I wrote to do DTD validation :

```
public static void Validate(string xmlToValidate, string documentType, string dtd)
    {
        try
        {
            Check.Argument.IsNotNullOrEmpty(documentType, "documentType");
            Check.Argument.IsNotNullOrEmpty(xmlToValidate, "xmlToValidate");
            Check.Argument.IsNotNullOrEmpty(dtd, "dtd");


            //clean the xml
            string xml = SanitizeXml(xmlToValidate);

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

            //append the dtd to the xml doc
            XmlDocumentType docType = xmlDoc.CreateDocumentType(documentType, null,      null, dtd);
            xmlDoc.AppendChild(docType);

            var xmlDeclaration = xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);

            xmlDoc.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaration, docType);

            xml = RemoveDeclaration(xml);

            //Append XML to the Xml Doc
            xmlDoc.AppendXml(xml);

            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
            settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD;

            settings.ValidationEventHandler += (sender, e) =>
            {
                throw new XmlException(e.Message, e.Exception);
            };

            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

            //save the xmlDoc content to the writer
            xmlDoc.Save(stringWriter);

            XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(stringWriter.ToString    ()), settings);

            //Parse the xml to check DTD conformance
            while (rdr.Read()) ;

            //Close
            rdr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            XmlException e = new XmlException(ex.Message, ex);
            throw e;
        }

    }Here's the string I'm testing with (but I'll be receiving it from external source) :

public const string XmlEMSOrder = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<Root>
  <OrderInformation>
    <Project>
      <ProjName>Project name </ProjName>
      <ContactName>Proj Contact </ContactName>
      <Phone>Proj Phone</Phone>
      <PONo>Project End User PO</PONo>
      <ProjectNo>Project# </ProjectNo>
      <RSPNo>Quote Trent</RSPNo>
      <SalesmanName>SalesFN1 SalesLN1</SalesmanName>
      <Salesman2Name>SalesFN2 SalesLN2</Salesman2Name>
      <Salesman3Name />
      <ACPONo>AC PO Number</ACPONo>
      <NationalAccountAgreement>1</NationalAccountAgreement>
      <Agreement />
      <AccountType />
      <HealthCare />
      <Government />
      <Other />
      <GovAccount>1</GovAccount>
       ....
```

Here is the Dtd I use :

```
             public const string Dtd = @"<!ELEMENT ACDiscount ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT ACPONo ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT AccountType EMPTY >

                                <!ELEMENT AddExistingSystem ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT AddOn EMPTY >

                                <!ELEMENT Address1 ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT Address2 ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT Address3 ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT AddressCity ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT AddressCountry ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT AddressCounty ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT AddressState EMPTY >

                                <!ELEMENT AddressZIP ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT Agreement EMPTY >

                                <!ELEMENT AmericanDisability ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT Article ( BlanketRelease | Color | Description | ExtraInfo | PartNo | Price | Qty | SCOLOR | ShipPromiseDate | ShipRequestDate | UOM | UnitPrice | characteristics )* >

                                <!ELEMENT AttachGridDrawing ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT BackToBack ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT BaseLocation ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT BaseName ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT BaseType EMPTY >

                                <!ELEMENT BidDueDate EMPTY >

                                <!ELEMENT BlanketOrRegular ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT BlanketRelease ( #PCDATA | ReleaseNumber | Status )* >

                                <!ELEMENT BoM ( #PCDATA | Position )* >

                                <!ELEMENT Books ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT Boxes ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT Cabinets ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT Cantilever ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT CarpetChoice ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT Carrier ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT CarrierCode ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT CarrierInstructions ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT ClearHeight ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT CollectPrepaid ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT Color ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT Comments ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT CompanyAddress1 ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT CompanyAddress2 ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT CompanyCity ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT CompanyContact ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT CompanyDepartment ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT CompanyName ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT CompanyPhone ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT CompanyZIP ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT ComponentLength ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT ComputerFloor ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT ConfiguraRoot ( #PCDATA | BoM | OrderInformation )* >

                                <!ELEMENT ConfirmedSettings ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT Contact ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT ContactName ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT ContractName ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT ContractNumber ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT ContractSSC ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT ContractType ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT CustomerCompany ( CompanyContact, CompanyName, CompanyAddress1, CompanyAddress2, CompanyCity, CompanyZIP, CompanyDepartment, CompanyPhone ) >

                                <!ELEMENT CustomerNumber ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT Delivery ( ShipRequestDate, RailFloorDate, Contact, Phone, Address1, Address2, Address3, AddressCity, AddressState, AddressZIP, ShipToContact, ShipToPhone, ShipToAddress1, ShipToAddress2, ShipToAddress3, ShipToAddressCity, ShipToAddressState, ShipToAddressZIP, Carrier, CarrierInstructions, RequireSupervision ) >

                                <!ELEMENT Department ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT Description ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT DrawnBy ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT EndUserDiscount ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT ExtraInfo ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT ExtranetLeadOrProj ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT Files ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT FloorMaterial ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT ForceOrder ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT GSA ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT GovAccount ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT Government EMPTY >

                                <!ELEMENT Group ( #PCDATA | ACDiscount | Article | Description | EndUserDiscount )* >

                                <!ELEMENT HasContractAgreement ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT HealthCare EMPTY >

                                <!ELEMENT HeightDepthRatio EMPTY >

                                <!ELEMENT Historical ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT IndustrialClip ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT IndustrialRacks ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT Installation ( MarketFocus, MarketFocusOther, Contact, Address1, Address2, Address3, AddressCity, AddressState, AddressZIP, AddressCounty, AddressCountry, Department, Phone, Files, Boxes, Books, Media, Other, OtherItems, materialStored, Historical, Relocation, PlanningComments ) >

                                <!ELEMENT IsMilitaryBase ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT LeadOrProj ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT Location ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT LvlGov ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT ManufactureOrStorage ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT MarketFocus EMPTY >

                                <!ELEMENT MarketFocusOther EMPTY >

                                <!ELEMENT Media ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT NationalAccountAgreement ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT NationalAccountNo EMPTY >

                                <!ELEMENT NationalAccountSubID EMPTY >

                                <!ELEMENT NewConstruction ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT NoOfShelves EMPTY >

                                <!ELEMENT NonSSCShelving ( Cantilever, Cabinets, PostCase, StackBoxFiles, WideSpan, Other, IndustrialClip, VerifiedDimensions, BackToBack, IndustrialRacks, OtherStr, PostType, VerifiedDimensionsStr, OverallDepth, OverallLength, OverallHeight, NoOfShelves ) >

                                <!ELEMENT OrderInfoRoom ( NewConstruction, AmericanDisability, ComputerFloor, AttachGridDrawing, RecessedOptions, ComponentLength, FloorMaterial, CarpetChoice, HeightDepthRatio, ClearHeight, Comments ) >

                                <!ELEMENT OrderInformation ( #PCDATA | BlanketRelease | Delivery | Installation | NonSSCShelving | OrderInfoRoom | Project )* >

                                <!ELEMENT OrderNumber ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT OrderType ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT OrderTypeProject ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT Other ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT OtherItems EMPTY >

                                <!ELEMENT OtherStr EMPTY >

                                <!ELEMENT OverallDepth EMPTY >

                                <!ELEMENT OverallHeight EMPTY >

                                <!ELEMENT OverallLength EMPTY >

                                <!ELEMENT PONo ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT PartNo ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT Phone ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT PlanningComments EMPTY >

                                <!ELEMENT Position ( #PCDATA | Description | Group )* >

                                <!ELEMENT PostCase ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT PostType EMPTY >

                                <!ELEMENT Price ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT ProjAddProjName ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT ProjAddSSCOrderNo ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT ProjName ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT Project ( ProjName, ContactName, Phone, PONo, ProjectNo, RSPNo, SalesmanName, Salesman2Name, Salesman3Name, ACPONo, NationalAccountAgreement, Agreement, AccountType, HealthCare, Government, Other, GovAccount, LvlGov, GSA, HasContractAgreement, ContractType, ContractName, ContractSSC, ContractNumber, IsMilitaryBase, BaseLocation, BaseName, BaseType, ManufactureOrStorage, QS, SpecialQuote, UseOldPricing, ExtranetLeadOrProj, LeadOrProj, AddExistingSystem, ProjAddSSCOrderNo, ProjAddProjName, DrawnBy, SICCode, Comments, BidDueDate, ConfirmedSettings, CustomerCompany, NationalAccountNo, NationalAccountSubID, SalesRep1, SalesRep2, SalesRep3, System, SystemType, SIC, Location, CollectPrepaid, RefersTo, AddOn, OrderType, OrderTypeProject, BlanketOrRegular, CarrierCode, SourceEmail, CustomerNumber, ShipRequestDate, RFShipRequestDate, OrderNumber, Status, ForceOrder ) >

                                <!ELEMENT ProjectNo ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT QS ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT Qty ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT RFShipRequestDate ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT RSPNo ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT RailFloorDate ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT RecessedOptions ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT RefersTo EMPTY >

                                <!ELEMENT ReleaseNumber ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT Relocation ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT RequireSupervision ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT SCOLOR ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT SIC ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT SICCode ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT SalesRep1 ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT SalesRep2 ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT SalesRep3 ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT Salesman2Name ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT Salesman3Name EMPTY >

                                <!ELEMENT SalesmanName ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT ShipPromiseDate ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT ShipRequestDate ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT ShipToAddress1 ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT ShipToAddress2 ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT ShipToAddress3 ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT ShipToAddressCity ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT ShipToAddressState EMPTY >

                                <!ELEMENT ShipToAddressZIP ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT ShipToContact ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT ShipToPhone ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT SourceEmail EMPTY >

                                <!ELEMENT SpecialQuote ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT StackBoxFiles ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT Status ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT System ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT SystemType EMPTY >

                                <!ELEMENT UOM ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT UnitPrice ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT UseOldPricing ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT VerifiedDimensions ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT VerifiedDimensionsStr EMPTY >

                                <!ELEMENT WideSpan ( #PCDATA ) >

                                <!ELEMENT characteristics EMPTY >

                                <!ELEMENT materialStored ( #PCDATA ) >";
```

Comment: Do you have the string for us? Are you missing quotes around things like attribute values? Just showing the exception isn't all that useful. Show us some simplified code and simplified data.

Comment: @Ritch, I just posted the code and data.

Comment: That XML parses for me. Are you sure its not something with the DTD? (Which isn't posted)

Comment: Thanks for the data - is _all_ of that necessary in order to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @John - I agree, but it cuts and pastes pretty easy. It parses as valid XML just fine though.

Comment: @Ritch: it will turn out to be an issue with his DTD. He should narrow down the XML to the smallest example that has the problem, then post that example along with the DTD.

Comment: from the exception message, I can't pinpoint the error on the DTD. I just posted it on the question.

Comment: @John - I agree. I was just stating my experiences with it.

Comment: @Attilah - This is getting a bit too complex. Can you simplify this down to the smallest bit of XML and DTD that fails for you?

Comment: I tried to narrow the exception down. but I don't know exactly which xml throws the error. all I do know is that the code portion : while(rdr.Read()); executes 3 times before the error throws. I don't know if that means it's at line number 3 that the faulty character is located.

Comment: After changing and executing the loop as follow : while (rdr.Read()) { b.Append(rdr.Name); b.Append(rdr.Value); }   I noticed the execution stops at <characteristics> xml part.

Answer (score 1):

in the DTD, I switched this :

```
<!ELEMENT characteristics EMPTY >
```

to :

```
<!ELEMENT characteristics ANY >
```

this is the portion of the xml concerned :

```
 <characteristics></characteristics>
```